# Adding 'Forgotten Password' To CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, passwords, captcha, forgot-password

I have just built a new site using CakePHP 2.3.something and I looking what I want to add / change to the site. The 1st big change is that I have only one password field input and not two, this is a simple change and check but I also don't have a forgotten password option on my site.

So this needs to change and I have been doing some research into this and think I found a very good walk though,

http://www.designaeon.com/cakephp-reset-forgot-password-via-email/

However my question is mainly do to how safe this is to use, has the reset could be done with just knowing the users email. I think it would not take much to add extra checks e.g. username and first name. But should I add something like CAPTCHA input into it as well. Has this would make sure the user was real and not some dam bot.

I have used re-CAPTCHA a little and it is not a hard plugin to use, so adding it in should not be and issues, but I know this pisses a lot of users off, it does me! But I am think about security and to make my users details / my site the safe place.

Many thanks for any thoughts on this...

Glenn.

Comment: Tip: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/#changepassword as I would not store those tokens in the same user table. There are different processes using those and a single table field (compared to a clean model + table) for each seems overhead to me.

Comment: Besides that I don't think your question is suitable for posting here in SO as you seem to be merely gathering thoughts on this. You should have a specific coding question one can give a specific answer to, though.

Answer (score 0):

May this can solve you problem 
[Forgot-passowrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041853/forgot-password-function-in-cakephp-2-0/20080776#20080776)
. As restetkey is updated after reseting password, no one can use same link again to reset passowrd. So It is safe.