# forgot password function in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, forgot-password

im very new in programming and php..I'm looking to create a simple Forgot Password system using CakePHP where a user will type in their username/email and then receive an email with a link they can click to create a new password.

I've Googled around but not found anything :/

**does anyone can help me or give me the link to easy tutorial in cakephp for forgot or reset password??**

Comment: which cakephp version you are using ?

Comment: @Aladdin cakephp 2.xx

Comment: https://github.com/chetanvarshney/User-Management-Plugin-for-Cakephp-2.x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is the easier that I found and it works!!

http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/34E99D#

Comment: Cant really have an external link for an answer.. what guarantees the link will work in the future..

Answer (score 15):

**Update**

> Add resetkey field in usertable.

in **UserModel** create `beforeSave` action and add this line in that action

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
            parent::beforeSave($options = array());
            if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
                $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
            }
            $this->data['User']['resetkey'] = Security::hash(mt_rand(),'md5',true);
            return true;
        }
```

When user apply for forgot passowrd, send this resetkey to his email.
**SomeController**
**this is hint of forgot action**

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $mail = $this->request->data['User']['mail'];
    $data = $this->User->findByMail($mail);
    $key = $data['User']['resetkey'];
    if(!$data) {
        $message = __('No Such E-mail address registerd with us ');
        $this->Session->setFlash($message,'flash',array('alert'=>'error'));
    } else {
        $key = $data['User']['resetkey'];
        $id = $data['User']['id'];
        $mail = $data['User']['email'];
        $email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
        $email->to($mail);
        $email->from("service@localhost.com");
        $email->emailFormat('html');
        $email->subject('Password reset instructions from');
        $email->viewVars(array('key'=>$key,'id'=>$id,'rand'=> mt_rand()));
        $email->template('reset');
        if($email->send('reset')) {
        $message = __('Please check your email for reset instructions.');
        $this->Session->setFlash($message,'flash',array('alert'=>'success'));
        } else {
            $message = __('Something went wrong with activation mail. Please try later.');
        $this->Session->setFlash($message,'flash',array('alert'=>'error'));
        }
    }
    $this->redirect('/');
}
```

Send that reset key to user so when User will change password, `Auth` will call `beforSave` save action and will update reset key. so no one can access rest password page using same key.
**Email Template**

> `App/View/Emails/reset.ctp`

```
<p>Please click on the link below to reset your password.</p>
<a href="http://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/reset/<?= $key .'BXX'.$rand.'XXB'. $id ?>/">Click here to reset your account password</a>
<hr />
<p>Alternatively, you can also copy paste the below link into your browser:
</p>
<p>http://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/reset/<?= $key .'BXX'.$rand.'XXB'. $id ?>/</p>
<p>This email was sent by <?= APPNAME ?>.</p>
```

You can define `APPNAME` in **`App/Config/bootstrap.php`** By adding following code

> `define('APPNAME','FooBar');`
> **this is hint of reset action**

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$a = func_get_args();
$keyPair = $a[0];
$key = explode('BXX', $keyPair);
$pair = explode('XXB',$key[1]);
$key = $key[0];
$pair = $pair[1];
$password = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
$uArr = $this->User->findById($pair);
if($uArr['User']['resetkey'] == $key) {
$this->User->read(null, $pair);
$this->User->set('password', $password);
if($this->User->save()) { 
$message = __('Your password has been reset');
$this->Session->setFlash($message,'flash',array('alert'=>'success')); 
} else {
$message = __('Something has gone wrong. Please try later or <b>sign up again</b>');
$this->Session->setFlash($message,'flash',array('alert'=>'alert')); }
} else {
$message = __('<b>Please check your reset link</b>');
$this->Session->setFlash($message, 'flash', array('alert'=> 'error'));
 }
```

**In Routs**

> `Router::connect('/reset/*',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'reset'));`
> And your forgot password function is ready

Comment: I forgot to give you exaple for resetpassword page `Router::connect('/reset/*',array('controller'=>'User','action'=>'reset'));`

Comment: See the updatated answer

Comment: im not very sure about "App/Config/bootstrap.php"..reset action..and the 'Router::connect('/reset/*',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'reset')); ' where should put this?

Comment: `Router::connect('/reset/*',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'reset'));` always goes inside **routs.php**

Comment: routs.php in what folder??

Comment: @Aryan I wanted to ask as I wasn't 100% sure how is the reset code working is it a form which has a submit button as when I put a submit button it wasn't working

Comment: thanks to @Aryan, i implemented it but was forced to save the user after generate a rand key : `$this->User->id=$id; //assign with current user
                        $mail = $data['User']['mail'];
                        //save the user with new key//
                        $this->User->save();` also needed to set the current user with the subchain in the reset action :`$this->User->id=$pair;`

Comment: beforeSave action will save/change randkey whenever forgot,reset and signup action will run, Check your `User` array again

Comment: Everything works fine except reset action code. I paste this code inside if($this->request->is(;post)) of resetpw function. I check $a. It is empty array. Thanks for your time @Aryan

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan : you don't get to use `func_get_args()` inside post method. User will click on the link "http://example.com/reset/example-reset-key-hashed-with-id" and he will go to reset password page. Where you will get reset key and id using `func_get_args()`